# CDH4 installation using tarball

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera, hadoop-yarn

I have been struggling to install CDH via tarball, there is no document that describes the steps or guides through. I do have root access on the server & wish to install CDH4 via tarball in Pseudo mode. Can anyone help?. On the same server apache hadoop is also installed, i want to install this CDH, without effecting the existing apache hadoop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It will not work..because in the end CDH4 will use the same ports which your existing apache hadoop is using..It will work ..if you shutdown your existing hadoop cluster and then start your CDH4 cluster. Or else change all the port numbers for namenode,secondary namenode,jobtracker, tasktracker and datanode and their respective web UI's port..which is kind of tedious.. It would be also helpful if you provide some error logs..So I can highlight what exactly is the problem.

Comment: Hi Debarshi, first of all thank you for your reply. I will shutdown existing hadoop cluster and then only I will start CDH4 cluster. Can you pls. tell me detailed process of installing CDH4 using tarball. My ultimate aim is to install impala. Is it possible to install impala on existing hadoop cluster?. I ask this question because in impala installation guide they mentioned CDH4 as mandatory. If not possible pls. guide me in installation of CDH4 using tarball.

Comment: Well..see what I can suggest is that with a small hack..everything can happen on everyone in hadoop..Im sure which version of hadoop you are using

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer please hit the vote button

Comment: Also..since CDH4 uses mapreduce 2.0 .. I think if your existing hadoop cluster is not 2.0.x then it will not work

Comment: my existing hadoop cluster is not 2.0.x, it will be older version than 2.0. so, can you pls. guide me in installing CDH4 using tarball?

Comment: Well..installation is that same as the support site..Are you facing any trouble? Please be specific

Comment: Actually in the support site of Cloudera, they gave complete procedure to install manually using yum commands for CentOS. They didn't gave complete procedure to install using tarball. They just mentioned like if you install using tarball, you have to install YARN. This is the link https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDH4DOC/CDH4+Installation. Upto now , I just downloaded the tarball file of cloudera hadoop and untar it  into a folder.

Comment: Well..so far I am happy with MRv1...I have never thought of using YARN 2.0 because it wont come into the picture..will take time..But anyways...Read the instruction in the red box..it says..YARN and MRv1 has same set of configuration files..it means the .xml files configurations will be same.. But I recommend you to follow this http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/SingleCluster.html

Comment: Thanx Debarshi. In the link you gave there is a note as NOTE: The following instructions assume you have hdfs running. can i use same way as i did to set the previous apache hadoop cluster?. for that i followed michael G. noll guide to set up single node cluster.

Comment: exactly...or you can use my tool for auto-clustering :P

Comment: You can add me on linkedin for more help